'visit someone' vs. 'visit with someone'
I am wondering what difference between 'visit someone' and 'visit with someone' there is.
In Oxford Learner’s Dictionaries

Visit with
(North American English)
to spend time with somebody, especially talking socially

Come and visit with me some time.


In the same dictionary:

visit with somebody
to spend time with someone, especially talking socially

Come and visit with me some time.


The (“North American English”) marker is absent.
In Cambridge Dictionary the (“North American English”) marker is absent too. And the example sentence is quite confusing:


My grandmother was visiting with one of her friends on the porch.


Does it mean that the grandma went to her friend's house?
Would the sentence “My grandmother was visiting one of her friends on the porch.” mean something else or sound differently?
Other examples:


She is starting to visit with friends more.
I was visiting with a couple of uncles and one asked how I'm doing with my graduate program.
Now let's visit with our special guest today: he's a big-time novelist.


From the Cambridge Dictionary entry. See screenshot below:


Note that, although your screenshot doesn't say 'North American', it does say US. Oxford Languages says INFORMAL NORTH AMERICAN - chat. (As a British English speaker, I would never use the word without implying 'going to see' someone.)

'Visit with' and 'meet with' are definitely Americansims.

In BrE if you said "I'm visiting with X" you would definitely mean you and X were visiting a third party together.

It doesn't say North American in the second case because it's from the Oxford Advanced American Dictionary!

You see an empty box, I see an en dash. Click on it and the "fewer examples" disappear, it is a piece of instruction telling the visitor the examples can be reduced and they are closable. Hence  the offensive part criticising (unfairly) the editors has been deleted.

Transitive visit with direct object:

We're going to visit grandma for the holiday.

refers to the act of going to grandma's house to be with her for a while, a day, or a few days, or possibly longer, but not permanently.
visit with (as we use it in American English) refers to being with them, having made the trip to visit them.
So it's just a matter of emphasis.  The version with the prepositional phrase emphasizes the interactive aspect, spending time with them.
P.S. I have never heard "visiting with" where the visited party was the subject:

Grandma was visiting with a friend who had come by to see her when we phoned, so we said we'd call her back later.

but I suspect that may be a regional (southern, southern-diaspora) usage.

Nothing wrong with this answer for American English, but it's worth emphasising (again) that "visit with X", meaning X is the person being visited is never used in British English.

Didn't think that was necessary given the "southern diaspora" reference,  and the question itself. But I will make it explicit since answers can  be used out of context.
